# Error Code 1062 MySQL

Tags: mysql-error-1062

Keeping on Getting error code.

Here's my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOCATION_tbl ( locationid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                                                                 locationcity VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                           locationregion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                                                                                                       locationcountry VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                                                                                                                                                   PRIMARY KEY (locationid) USE lab3b;

INSERT INTO LOCATION_tbl (locationid, locationcity, locationregion, locationcountry)
VALUES ('GRU',
        'Sao Paulo',
        'Sao Paulo',
        'Brazil');

INSERT INTO LOCATION_tbl
VALUES ('CPT',
        'Cape Town',
        'Western Cape',
        'South Africa');

INSERT INTO LOCATION_tbl
VALUES ('BOG',
        'Bogota',
        'Capital District' ,
        'Colombia');

INSERT INTO LOCATION_tbl
VALUES ('HAN',
        'Hanoi',
        'Som Tay',
        'Vietnam');

INSERT INTO LOCATION_tbl
VALUES ('MUC',
        'Munich',
        'Bavaria',
        'Germany')
```

Help anyone??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a closing ')' from your create table statement